# jQuery datatables plugin too slow - need a replacement

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I've been using jQuery [datatables plugin](http://datatables.net/) for about two years now and it worked great so far. The problem occured now when I need to load about **45000** records at once (you click the button and wait for the page with the data to load) - the loading time is just too big to wait.

Here are the tests I made using Chrome web browser (the data is from it's Network tab using ):

*datatables plugin turned on:*
**5476** records:
`24 requests  ❘  256.26KB transferred  ❘  19.80s

(onload: 19.80s, DOMContentLoaded: 18.58s)`
**45071** records:
`34 requests  ❘  1.85MB transferred  ❘  11.1min

(onload: 11.1min, DOMContentLoaded: 11.0min)`

*datatables plugin turned off (the jQuery datatables initialization is comented out):*
**5476** records:
`21 requests  ❘  255.84KB transferred  ❘  6.57s

(onload: 13.26s, DOMContentLoaded: 13.28s)`

**45071** records:
`31 requests  ❘  1.84MB transferred  ❘  2.0min

(onload: 2.0min, DOMContentLoaded: 2.0min)`

The *increase in load time* that datatables make is over **80%** for the 45k rows, and almost **40%** for the 5k rows.

So I was wondering if you guys know of any similar plugin that handles alot of rows (45000+) faster, or am I just missing the point by trying to load all 45000+ records in "one go"?

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: I'd say you're missing the point, 45000 rows is a huge dataset to handle in a browser.  Maybe you should be looking at loading smaller views of the data and paginating

Comment: Is there any reason you *need* to load that many records at once? That'll slow down pretty much anything...

Comment: i would suggest that the time delay may not be the pulling the data but the dom manipulation. Have you looked at optimising your existing jquery code?

Comment: @NicholasKing: that was my suspicion too, that's why I made the test which confirm that. For the optimization - I really don't know what more optimization I can do to jQuery datatables call, as I call it simply by  
    $('#example').dataTable({  
        "bJQueryUI": true,  
        "iDisplayLength": 50  
    });`

Comment: do you use server `Server side processing` ? you can use it with pagination , so eventually at any current time you will work with a small portion of rows in client side....

Comment: @Daniel: ok, now I googled and I [found what you mean](http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) and I'll take a look at it. Thx!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From the DataTables FAQs ( http://datatables.net/faqs#speed ):

- Client-side processing - DOM sourced data: ~5'000 rows. Speed options: bSortClasses
- Client-side processing - Ajax sourced data: ~50'000 rows. Speed options: bDeferRender
- Server-side processing: millions of rows.

If you aren't using deferred rendering at the moment, with your 45'000 rows, I would most certainly suggest that. Failing that, for DataTables options, you might need to look at [server-side processing](http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html).

Answer (score 4):

The answer by Allan is good; but one other thing to mention (which greatly effects the loading time) is setting `bProcessing` and `bServerSide` to true as shown in the code below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "../examples_support/server_processing.php"
    } );
} );
```

Ref. http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

My code was taking 15 seconds to load, now it takes like 1 second :)

Comment: `bProcessing` isn't just and option to show a message while _DataTables_ is loading the data? How could it speed up loading time?

Comment: It's not the `bProcessing` that speeds it up; just the `bServerSide`.

Comment: Isn't that pretty much what Allan said?

Answer (score 1):

I found that browser plugins can also slow the performance of the DataTable down, which was in my case. The loading time for the table itself went from about 15s to 2s.

One of them is **Skype Toolbar**, which automatically parses data in the table, unless you tell it not to.

This is a problem for huge tables. Lot of users have that plugin and it unknowingly slows their loading of large tables.

There is one good solution for this, add this to the header. Every DataTables web page that goes to the public should contain this:

```
<meta name="SKYPE_TOOLBAR" content="SKYPE_TOOLBAR_PARSER_COMPATIBLE" />
```